# "authorizationError": "DEVELOPER_TOKEN_PROHIBITED"

Tags: oauth2-playground

We have a standard access developer token and have followed the guidance from /google-ads/api/docs/get-started/next-steps
But when doing request based on client id and developer token from Oauth 2.0 we get error and it seems to relate to message": "Developer token is not allowed with project 'xxxxxxxx'(I deleted the project number).
However I can't tell where this project number is picked up.
If I look at my projects the ID's is not the project number that is defined in error.
How/where do I change this?